# Swagger PHP, model doesn't work

Tags: php, swagger

I can't get this to work with my model; both with the "comment" way and the code way.

Can anyone please help me out? The "type" field on the operation annotations don't take any effect.

```
    $swagger = $this->app["swagger"];

    $swagger->models["user"] = new \Swagger\Annotations\Model([
        "id" => "user",
        "properties" => array(
            new \Swagger\Annotations\Property([
                "name" => "test", "type"=>"string"
            ])
        )
    ]);

    $path="/users";
    $name="user";
    $serivce = "Users";

    $swagger->registry[$path] = new \Swagger\Annotations\Resource([
        'resourcePath' => $path,
        'basePath'=>"/".$this->app['api.version'],
        'apis' => array(
            new \Swagger\Annotations\API([
                'path' => $path,
                'operations' => array(
                    new \Swagger\Annotations\Operation([
                        'method' => "GET",
                        'summary' => "Returns a list of ".ucfirst($service),
                        'nickname' => "GetAll".ucfirst($service),
                        'type' => "user",
                    ]),
                )
            ])
        )
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wee, I got it ..

```
$swagger->registry[$path] = new \Swagger\Annotations\Resource([
            'resourcePath' => $path,
            'basePath'=>"/api/".$this->app['api.version'],
            'models' => ($swagger->models[$name]->id ? array($name=>$swagger->models[$name]) : []),
            ....
```